# Showing that the claim $I(X;Y) = I(X;Z)= 0 \implies I(X;Y;Z) = 0$ is true for jointly normal random variables only.

Tags: normal-distribution, information-theory, mutual-information

If we have three random variables $X,Y,Z$, which are jointly normal, how can it be shown that $I(X;Y) = I(X;Z)= 0 \implies I(X;Y;Z) = 0$?

I know that for jointly normal distributions $X,Y,Z$: $I(X;Y) = \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{\det(\Sigma_X) \det(\Sigma_Y)}{\det(\Sigma_{XY})}$. Knowing this much, how can I move on from here?

And how is this not true for the general case of jointly (non-normal) distributed random variables $X,Y,Z$?

Comment: Hint: $I(X;Y;Z) = I(X;Y) - I(X;Y|Z) = I(X;Y) + I(X;Z) - I(X;Y,Z)$. Now, if I tell you that $I(X;Y) = I(X;Z) = 0,$ then $I(X;Y;Z) = 0 \iff I(X;Y,Z) = 0$. Now, what does $I(X;Y) = 0$ say about the random variables $(X,Y)$? Using this, can you interpret what the original implication is saying? If so, you can attack this via the standard development of conditional densities of multivariate Gaussians, and the last line falls to a very standard counterexample.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint What do you mean by "the last line falls to a very standard counterexample"?

Comment: Assuming you've worked through things,  the Q is asking you to show  that for jointly Gaussian $X,Y,Z,$ if $X$ is independent of $Y$ and $X$ is independent of $Z$, then it is also jointly independent of $(Y,Z)$. The standard counterexample for this is as follows. Take $Y$ and $Z$ to be independent fair bits, and take $X$ to be their XOR. I'll leave it to you to work out the details.